# DJANGO Insert Data Into Form Field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

What i am trying to accomplish is insert the Word "YES" into my field if the following condition is met.

`if K8Points.objects.filter(student_name=studentpsid).exists() and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame='9:30AM - 10:00AM' ).exists() and grand_total >= 20:`

Then once the field is filled in with the word YES. The form is considered valid and will save. How do i do this ? Thanks

Full Code

```
def Student_Progress(request, studentpsid):
        if request.method == 'POST':
           form = K8Points_Score(request.POST)
           studentid = Student.objects.get(studentpsid=studentpsid)
           date = datetime.date.today()
           academic = K8Points.objects.values_list('academic', flat = True).filter(student_name_id=studentpsid)
           behavior = K8Points.objects.values_list('behavior', flat = True).filter(student_name_id=studentpsid)
           academic_total = 0
           behav_total = 0
           for score in academic: 
                academic_total += int(score)
           for score in behavior:
                behav_total += int(score)

           grand_total = academic_total + behav_total    
           counseling = Student.objects.values_list('counseling_goal', flat = True).get(studentpsid=studentpsid)
           if K8Points.objects.filter(student_name=studentpsid).exists() and K8Points.objects.filter(time_frame='9:30AM - 10:00AM' ).exists() and grand_total >= 20:  
                if form.is_valid():
                   morning_recess = form.cleaned_data.get(morning_recess= "YES") 
                   form.save
                   return render(request, 'points/student_progress.html', {'form': form,'studentid': studentid ,'date':date, 'counseling': counseling, 'grand_total':grand_total, 'academic_total': academic_total, 'behav_total': behav_total,'morning_recess': morning_recess } ) 

                elif K8Points.objects.filter(student_name=studentpsid).exists():
                   form = K8Points_Score()  
                   studentid = Student.objects.get(studentpsid=studentpsid)
                   date = datetime.date.today()
                   academic = K8Points.objects.values_list('academic', flat = True).filter(student_name_id=studentpsid)
                   behavior = K8Points.objects.values_list('behavior', flat = True).filter(student_name_id=studentpsid)
                   academic_total = 0
                   behav_total = 0
                   for score in academic: 
                     academic_total += int(score)
                   for score in behavior:
                     behav_total += int(score)

                   grand_total = academic_total + behav_total    
                   counseling = Student.objects.values_list('counseling_goal', flat = True).get(studentpsid=studentpsid)
                   return render(request, 'points/student_progress.html', {'form':form , 'studentid': studentid ,'date':date, 'counseling': counseling, 'grand_total':grand_total, 'academic_total': academic_total, 'behav_total': behav_total,  } ) 
        else:
            return render(request,'points/student_progress_none.html' )
```

Comment: Should be `form.save()`

Comment: so form.save() was an issue however, my code still doesnt work.

Comment: morning_recess = K8_Points.objects.get(morning_recess='morning_recess')  this line here is wrong. What im trying to do is insert YES into the form field morning_recess if that IF statement is True.